# Do enhancements carry over to new equipment?

Tags: moonlighter

In *Moonlighter* if I were to use a piece of enhanced equipment as a component in crafting a new piece of equipment would any enhancements I placed on the original part carry over to the new piece?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they don't carry over.

At first I thought this was annoying, but then I realised how easy it is to get money.

Also, if they did carry over it would be game breaking, as you could just get the cheap enhancements at the start and never have to pay the cost of the later enhancements.